# is the a similar concept as sql "union" in FT.SEARCH rediSearch in redis databases?

Tags: laravel, redis, lua

is there any similar concept as sql'union in RediSearch?
in my scenario user need to fetch an query autocompletion based on filters applied on different rediSearch Schema.
I'm using Laravel10 and because the lack of laravel10 RediSeach packages i'm using prepared Laravel Facade / Redis database LUA scripting:
something like this:

```
$redis->eval(<<<"LUA"
        redis.call('FT.CREATE' , 'user-value' , 'ON' , 'HASH' , 'PREFIX' , 1 , 'user:value:' , 'schema' , 'MY_DATA_AS_NUMBER' , 'NUMERIC' , 'sortable')
        LUA, 0);
```

```
$redis->eval(<<<"LUA"
        redis.call('FT.ADD' , 'user-value' , KEYS[1] , 1.0 , 'FIELDS' , 'MY_DATA_AS_NUMBER' , ARGV[1])
        LUA, 1, 'user:value:1', 2335423543);
```

after that i'm ok to search my `user:value:` prefixed Hashes to search a numeric range using this query

```
$var = $redis->eval(<<<"LUA"
        return redis.call('FT.SEARCH' , 'user-value:'  , '@MY_DATA_AS_NUMBER:[2335423542 2335423544]')
        LUA, 0);
```

In my scenario, I want to search another Hash list with similar SCHEMA prefixed by `organization:value:` and then union these two search return values (prohibit possible duplicate)

Does any approach come to your mind?